# function to reverse DateTime::createFromFormat / date_create_from_format

Tags: php, datetime, format

I'm accidently made mistake by convert string to date with wrong format (month to date). So here's what I have done:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '12/26/1987')->format("d/m/Y");
```

so it is outputing wrong date, from 12/26/1987 became 10/02/1989 and I have save a lot of the wrong date to the database.
Is there any reverse method or enlightment to get the original date before it has been converted.

thank in advance

Comment: Does the database have the `12/26/1987` or `10/02/1989` date?

Comment: the value stored in database is only '10/02/1989' (the wrong format)

Comment: You have no information about the original date whatsoever? I'm not sure if this is possible without at least some info like the year

Comment: I dont have any information, except the wrong formatted stored in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lost information when you converted your date (1-31) into a month (1-12), so based on what I've seen, all of your improperly formatted dates can be one of 2-3 other dates. The following code prints out what the other possible dates are if you give it one of your wrong dates. I think that's about all you can do:

```
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '12/26/1987');

    $possible_dates = array();
    $remainder_start = 0;
    $days_in_month = array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);
    while ($remainder_start <= $days_in_month[intval($date->format("m")])
    {
        $possible_dates[] = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $date->format("d")."/".(intval($date->format("m"))+$remainder_start)."/".(intval($date->format("Y"))-($remainder_start/12)));
        $remainder_start += 12;
    }

    foreach ($possible_dates as $d)
    {
        echo $d->format("m/d/Y")."\n";
    }
```

This will print out `12/02/1989 12/14/1988 12/26/1987`

Your month will always be right even in the wrong date since you put that in the day position, but your years and days will be one of several combinations.

If the day in the original date was the 12th of the month or sooner your "wrong" date is actually still correct.

Comment: I've tried to modify that code, but I can not to get the right value.
for the lost information, is it can be extracted from the "wrong" date?
because all I have only that wrong date.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't get the original date, but you can get a few dates that it COULD be, sorry to tell you

Comment: so is it imposible to get the right one? 
too many possibility I get from that code with different of input

Comment: Yes I believe it is impossible

Comment: Thank you, this is the best answer I got

Comment: Thanks @moc4yu, sorry I couldn't be of more help